# Multiple topics in a single question

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

What is the SO policy if a beginner asks multiple questions within a single one? Here is the [justification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43832964/772868). Seems beginners have some limit there:

> Also I have another doubt and as we can only post from time to time I'd like to post it too:

Comment: In my opinion, a question should contain exactly one specific question. Especially if they are unrelated, multiple questions will make it harder to find and also harder to answer.

Comment: Just close as too broad. If we would allow this how would we vote or flag only part of a question. *Hey, I downvoted your question for your third and fourth question but the other ones are OK*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the meantime, the question referred to has been [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43832964/revisions) by its original author to be a single question again. This voids this meta question.

In general, as [rene](//meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) remarked in a [comment](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348891#comment471392_348891):

> Just close as too broad. If we would allow this, how would we vote or flag only part of a question? *Hey, I downvoted your question for your third and fourth question but the other ones are OK...*

Of course, leaving a comment to explain this to the original author is [nice](//stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) to do.

Comment: I'm fine with this answer, except I'd point out that not leaving a comment is not "not nice". Leaving a comment is always optional, especially as the Too Broad close reason leaves a notice with information as to why it was closed as such.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Your comment starts with a triple negative regarding a quality that is not binomial.